# Iterate through an array and excecute functions in order javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, asynchronous, promise

I'm struggling trying to iterate through an array while updating some content(string).
Currently, I have this code:

```
const replaceUrls = async (content: string) => {
  let allImgsUpdated = 0;
  let newContent = content;
  const oldImgs = content.match(/https?:\/\/.*\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|svg|gif)/gi);
  const newImages = ["first", "second"];

  if (oldImgs) {
    oldImgs.forEach((old, idx) => {
      try {
        newContent.replace(old, newImages[idx]);
      } finally {
        allImgsUpdated++;
      }
    });
  }

  if (oldImgs && oldImgs?.length >= allImgsUpdated) return newContent;
};
```

My objective is to update the newContent two oldImages urls (this is a test, later I will update the images to be dynamic to how much 'oldImages' I have) to the new ones. I did the allImgsUpdated workaround so I can return the newContent when the forEach already finished

Comment: `return` terminates the loop

Comment: @CertainPerformance but if I remove the 'return' and leave only await firstFunction(i)....., the allImgsUpdated++ runs, but the first function doesn't, it's weird

Comment: Why are you trying to `await firtsFunction()`?  `firtsFunction()` is entirely synchronous and should not be tagged `async` at all.  Then, remove the `return await` and the `.finally()`.  It appears you've made this code about 5x more complicated than required.  In fact, there's nothing asynchronous in ANY of the code you show.  It is all synchronous.  No need for `async`, `await` or promises anywhere here.  If this isn't all the real code, then please show us all the real code so we can see any actual asynchronous code.

Comment: Also, please don't name things `firtsFunction()` and `secondFunction()`.  Please give them names that describe what their purpose is.

Comment: Suppose you have an array `oldImgs` with (current) image file names & another array (say `newImgs` with corresponding new file names) & you need to replace old with new in some URL (say `content`) and return a new URL (say `newContent`), this is a straightforward + simple task. `let newContent = content; oldImgs.forEach((old, idx) => newContent.replace(old, newImgs[idx]));` You already generate `oldImgs` in your code using reg-ex match. Please try & share feedback.

Comment: Further, `firtsFunction()` does a `return newContent.replace(...)`, but then the caller doesn't use the returned result.  I'm having a hard time figuring out what this code is supposed to do.

Comment: Hi @jsN00b, thanks for answering! I edited my question to the new code I'm using.. still doesn't work, when I return from the function the newContent, it hasn't updated the urls. So I did this workaround, but still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with this workaround:

```
const replaceUrls = async (content: string) => {
  let allImgsUpdated = 0;
  let newContent = content;
  const oldImgs = content.match(/https?:\/\/.*\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|svg|gif)/gi);
  const newImages = ["primera", "segunda"];

  if (oldImgs) {
    oldImgs.forEach((old, idx) => {
      try {
        const updatedContent = newContent.replace(old, newImages[idx]);
        return (newContent = updatedContent);
      } finally {
        allImgsUpdated++;
      }
    });
  }

  if (oldImgs && oldImgs?.length >= allImgsUpdated) return newContent;
};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).